# Track down "Exception Thrown: " message in .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am building a NuGet, and in my Visual Studio Output window I am getting this:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in MyLibraryNameHere.dll

Obviously I have an invalid cast happening, but I am not able to find out where it is happening.

It does not cause any kind of break or stack trace or anything else that I can use to track it down.

I assume it is happening on a different thread than the main one, and that is why it is not causing a break to happen.

**Is there some way to get more information? Or have Visual Studio break the debugging when an error happens on a background thread?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Debug** menu select **Exception settings** and select all types of CLR exceptions (or just InvalidCastException in your case). Then the debugger will break on those exceptions even if you have an exception handler (try/catch block) in your code.

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings